# Javascript - Add images to a node in random positions

Tags: javascript, image, dom

I'm expecting from below script the positioning of a simple image at random positions in a DIV.
While the images do get displayed, they all appear side by side, while I can see on the console that the random positions are being generated.
Any hint, please?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function generateFaces(){
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
    while (numberOfFaces > 0) {
      var random_left = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
      var random_top = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
      var theImage = document.createElement("img");
      theImage.src = "face.png";
      theImage.style.top = '"'+random_top+'px"';
      console.log("top style: " + '"'+random_top+'px"');
      theImage.style.left = '"'+random_left+'px"';
      theLeftSide.appendChild(theImage);
      numberOfFaces--;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you need to add a position:relative or absolute to allow the top and left to be applied check [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Thanks happymacarts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

You need to set the position relative and also set the style like this.

```
theImage.style = "top:"+random_top+"px; left:"+random_left+"px; position:relative";
```

You can check in the developer console that the style you have added for image are not actually applied on the element.

```css
#leftSide
{
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftSide"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function generateFaces(){
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
    while (numberOfFaces > 0) {
      var random_left = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
      var random_top = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
      var theImage = document.createElement("img");
      
      theImage.src = "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9tLvsasK-kB72yV_zC8hn0qZhHbshQdXLELCXaF1JkWIOuYfUUsuMsw";
      theImage.style = "top:"+random_top+"px; left:"+random_left+"px; position:relative";
      theLeftSide.appendChild(theImage);
    
     
      numberOfFaces--;
    }
  }
  generateFaces();
</script>
```

Comment: an explanation would be helpful so the OP can understand what it is you have done instead of "here is the answer"

Comment: @happymacarts Yeah, was just editing the answer for explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Deep, for your deep answer. Appreciated.

Comment: Appreciated, @Deep.
I can now continue my exercise in peace.